# What is the complexity of this function

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have a function that performs a Mergesort on a list of n floats, then find and return a maximum element.

I know that the complexity of a Mergesort is `O(n*log(n))`, and I know that the complexity of max(list) is `O(n)`. So with that in mind, I have both `O(n*log(n))` and `O(n)`. As far as I know, the big O notation takes the fastest growing polynomial and ignore constants. Since in this case, n is the lower order term, does this mean this function has the complexity `O(n*log(n))`? Or does this rule only apply to polynomials?

Comment: does this mean this function has the complexity O(nlogn)? Yes.

Comment: n*log(n) dominates n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Big O notation describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.

So yes, if you have a polynomial, only the biggest thing counts, and constants and factors don't matter. For example, a function with complexity 4n² + 999n + 5 is in O(n²).

And in your case, yes, that means it's just O(n log n).